# Disqus application settings not saving, what to do?

Tags: javascript, jsonp, disqus

no matter what I am doing(new account, new site, new app), its not saving any settings. That means I can't add a domain to the whitelist and also, I can't get a public key.

Their own site's Javascript is extreme messy and crashes all over the place. I guess they won't fix all this any time soon. I tried to reach them multiple times through their contact page, but as expected  : no response.

I am wondering this is happening only to me. Can anyone confirm this ?

No I am facing the problem of receiving the data at all. I tried JSONP, JSON-REST over a proxy and some other things. When using JSONP without the api key (not the public), I am getting a HTTP 400 error.

Are there any alternatives to receiving the data through their API ? I can't use server side solutions.

well, any hints welcome.

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This sounds like a bug, and you should definitely contact us with your shortname and the browser you're using: http://disqus.com/support/

Comment: hi this seems to be occurring to me right now, can you give a quick fix or something? thanks. I'm using chrome right now Version 67.0.3396.99 (Official Build) (32-bit).